# Git merge already up to date, but diff shows differences

Tags: git

I've got a repository on bitbucket.

I download on a local machine, and work on master (commited all changes, push them too).

Then I had to work with a colleague and made my branch. Worked with my branch and improved a lot the project. Now, it's time to merge my branch to the master so my colleague gets the latest version.

I've tried to merge the branch and it does not work.

I tried

```
git merge -s ours master

git merge --strategy=ours master

etc... doesn't work
```

It always answer its up to date.

I've done git diff latest_branch..master and shows loads of changes.. What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try "git pull-request" ?

Comment: Usually, I do: "git checkout master" and then, "git merge other_branch"

Comment: Yeah...i did try that, but when i do git checkout master it show: error: your local changes to the file would be overwritten by checkout. If i do git chekcout -f master and then merge, shows already up to date...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did:

```
git checkout -f master
git merge other_branch
```

Finally worked, thanks to all and sorry!

Comment: `git checkout -f` throws away local changes. Instead, you should've dealt with them explicitly (commit/revert/stash).

Comment: Really? I didn't lost my changes... So if u say -f throws away local changes, don't know how i managed to make it work..